# Xcode 12, Swift 5.3: @Environment(\.colorScheme) Not Updating

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to achieve reading dark mode in my app built in SwiftUI, Xcode 12 and iOS14.

I am using this key to find wether or not it's in light or dark mode: `@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme`

My testing device is set to dark mode, but the environment variable is reading light mode.

I have tested this removing the app, reloading XCode, and restarting my Macbook Pro.

`User Interface Style` is not used since this is iOS14. ([SwiftUI: Dark mode not detected when testing on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59845579/swiftui-dark-mode-not-detected-when-testing-on-device))

**The weird thing is, my testing device (iPhone 11 Pro) renders non-background colored views as dark as they should. So the only thing that isn't updating is the variable colorScheme itself.** I am not changing that value anywhere in my app programatically.

I also checked that my info.plist is routed properly in the build settings of the target. I am using a target for the main app, and a target for a widget extension.

What am I Missing?

Comment: The `.colorScheme` reads system appearance, why do you expect it reacts on changed Info.plist?

Comment: @Asperi I expected it to read `Dark` when it's set to `Dark` in the Info.plist.  per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537855/is-it-possible-to-opt-out-of-dark-mode-on-ios-13?rq=1 - Clearly I misunderstood that usage.

Comment: Edited the question to reflect that understanding

Answer (score 10):

In my project, I found `@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme` Get the color scheme of your software, not the color scheme of the system.

So when you manually change the color scheme of the software itself, `@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme` You can’t get the phone’s color scheme again.

Use the following code instead, it will get you the color scheme of the phone

```
let currentSystemScheme = UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle
```

It should be noted that `userInterfaceStyle` and  `colorScheme` are not the same type, so you may need the following code to convert

```
func schemeTransform(userInterfaceStyle:UIUserInterfaceStyle) -> ColorScheme {
    if userInterfaceStyle == .light {
        return .light
    }else if userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
        return .dark
    }
    return .light}
```

Comment: I used a ViewModel combined with UserDefault to allow users to switch between maintaining color mode and following the system. If you need more detailed code, you can reply to me

Comment: Can you please give some detailed code ?

Answer (score 8):

I just found out why

I am reading `@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme` too early in the apps lifecycle.

When I open the app, I create my data class BEFORE the app had finished initializing. I was calling the `@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme` in this data class.

I tested using `@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme` on a view once the app finished initializing with `.onAppear()` and it worked as it should have

Comment: Also, using `@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme`  in an `@environmentobject` does not change from my testing. I had to reference it in a view and it worked properly.

Comment: Very good. I observed the same behaviour using the new **SwiftUI lifecycle**. The colorScheme has to be read in the first `View` rather than the `App` struct.

Comment: YES! This is how I am handing this in `body` of my view:

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ...
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)) { _ in
                broughtToForeground = true // an @State property
        }
    }
    .onAppear {
        if broughtToForeground {
            updateColors()
            broughtToForeground = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also don't use it on your `@main App struct`, it wont work properly that way

Answer (score 0):

> I expected it to read Dark when it's set to Dark in the Info.plist. per …

Hmm... Apple's documentation says *enumerates the user setting options* (see below complete snapshot):

```
/// The possible types of color schemes, like Dark Mode.
///
/// The color scheme enumerates the user setting options for Light or Dark Mode.
/// It also provides the light or dark options for any particular view when the
/// app wants to override the user setting.
@available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public enum ColorScheme : CaseIterable {

    case light

    case dark
```

Comment: Yes I'm following you, thanks for the comment. I updated my original question. The issue is that `@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme` isn't updating to the devices mode. My test device is in dark mode and the app is reading light mode.